# Chromecast Expanded Controller, Tracks Chooser dialog crashes the app after 11.0.2 update

Tags: java, android, chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

When users want to change AUDIO Track, chromecast tracks chooser dialog crashes the app. It started to happen when "play-services-cast-framework" updates 10.2.6 to 11.0.2

Is it known bug? Or how do I fix it?

**Play Services 11.2.0 published but nothing changed...**

> ### Error in logcat
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long
>   com.google.android.gms.cast.MediaTrack.getId()' on a null object
>   reference
>                                                                                  at
>   com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.TracksChooserDialogFragment.zza(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.TracksChooserDialogFragment.zza(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.zzak.onClick(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:175)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)

**Gradle Dependencies**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:11.0.2' 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.0.2'
```

Comment: What does your gradle build dependencies look like?

Comment: Hi, @MorrisonChang dependencies looks like below: 

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.2'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.0.2

Comment: edit your original post to include additional information

Comment: Play Services 11.2.0 published but nothing changed... No one else is experiencing this problem?

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known bug, reported in the issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64796099